# SignalR Hub method not being called again

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm using AspNetCore SignalR in my app. I have server code:

```
   public class Broadcast : Hub
   {
        public async Task AddRow(Guid tableId)
        {
            RecordView newRow = _tableService.AddRow(tableId);

            await Clients.Group(tableId.ToString()).SendAsync("AddRow", newRow);
        }

    }
```

And I have client code:

```
function addRow() {
    hubConnection.send("AddRow", useTables().tableId)
        .then(() => {
            console.log("AddRow Success!")
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("AddRow error: ", err)
        })
}
```

When I call the AddRow method for the first time everything works fine. But next time the method is not called. This is what I see in the debugger.

I think this is because the server only allows one call at a time and the server is waiting for the task to complete. And if I set the property MaximumParallelInvocationsPerClient = 2, then the AddRow method is called twice, and the third time again does not work. But I don't understand why the task is not considered completed after executing the code:

```
await Clients.Group(tableId.ToString()).SendAsync("AddRow", newRow);
```

Comment: What is your _tableService? Is it a background service?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
I have an object called Row and I write it to the database when I call the _tableService.AddRow(tableId) service. To write to the database, I use the Entity Framework. And after I add a new object through DBContext, I need to call a method that will write the changes to the database. The error was when I called the SaveChangesAsync() asynchronous method. When I changed the method to synchronous SaveChanges() the error disappeared

Maybe someone can explain why that is?

Comment: Could you please tell me which codes you have modified to solve the issue? Add await?

Comment: I have an object called Row and I write it to the database when I call the _tableService.AddRow(tableId) service. To write to the database, I use the Entity Framework. And after I add a new object through DBContext, I need to call a method that will write the changes to the database. The error was when I called the SaveChangesAsync() asynchronous method. When I changed the method to synchronous SaveChanges() the error disappeared

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).